# Typo3 : Enable last-modified on sendCacheHeaders

Tags: http-headers, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, last-modified

I've setup a TYPO3 7.6.x website and I need to enable the last-modified on response header.

I added the following TypoScript to my root template

```
config {
  contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
  no_cache = 0
  sendCacheHeaders = 1
  enableContentLengthHeader = 1
  cache_period = 3600
  cache_clearAtMidnight = 1
```

but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/7.6/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#sendcacheheaders), the Last-Modified header is sent, when these requirements are met:

- page was cached
- No *_INT or *_EXT objects were on the page (e.g. USER_INT)
- No frontend user is logged in
- No backend user is logged in

So for testing you maybe need to use a different browser or log out from your current session.

Comment: Even with these requirements the `Last-Modified` not sent (Screenshot) https://i.ibb.co/1JqHdyx/image.png